# java japplet not accepting input

Tags: java, input, applet

I'm working on a java applet/desktop application. It runs directly on the desktop, and should also run as a jApplet in a web browser. I'm having some problems though that only occur when the program is running in a web browser. The first is I have some text box's in the application and for some reason they don't accept input. The second is when I press a button, the button kinda fires, but then doesn't actually call a method. I'm not sure what is causing that. 
http://24.111.117.77/skylabs/nolimits/index.php
that's the link to the application so you can see what I mean. And also, when you press login, you should see that a socket connection was made, and a login attempt in the overhead console...but it doesn't show on the web app. Theres quite a bit of code so if anyone has an idea by looking at it, that'd be great. Thanks.

I'm using Swing...and also it doesn't work right as an applet, but it works perfectly as a standalone application.

Comment: It might help if you post some code for the login window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using AWT give your text field a width.

```
TextField textField = new TextField("", 20);
```

also

```
setEnabled();
```